# Add Library to Gradle Kotlin app

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I converted simple Kitlon file into Library, the file is:

`Display.kt`:

```
package hello  

fun main(args: Array<String>) {   
   println("Hello World!")        
}
```

had been compiled into library using the command:

```
kotlinc Display.kt -d Display.jar
```

The output had been cross checked to be worked using the command:

```
kotlin -classpath Display.jar hello.DisplayKt
```

Then I moved it to folder `src/main/resources`, then tried calling it from another app, using the below code:

`Hello.kt`:

```
package hello 

import hello.DisplayKt

fun main(args: Array<String>) {   
   println("Hi")        
}
```

and defined the `build.gradle` file as below (tried to put all option I read about to solve my case):

```
// set up the kotlin-gradle plugin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

// apply the kotlin-gradle plugin
apply plugin: "kotlin"


// add kotlin-stdlib dependencies.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //dependencies from a remote repositor
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    //local file
    compile files('src/main/resources/Display.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources', include: '*.jar')
}

jar {
    manifest {
        //Define mainClassName as: '[your_namespace].[your_arctifact]Kt'
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'hello.HelloKt', "Implementation-Title": "Gradle",
                   "Implementation-Version": 1)
    }

    // NEW LINE HERE !!!
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/kotlin']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

but, after running `gradle build` command, I got the below error:

`Unresolved reference: DisplayKt`

Note: I'm very very new to JAVA/KOTLIN and GRADLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, the full path of the function is `hello.main`